# Why does this "simple" `load` function not "work"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, alert

sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#test').load(function(){
     alert(1);
    });
  });
 </script>
  <TITLE> test load </TITLE>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
 TEST
</div>
</BODY>
```

Comment: You forgot to read the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(window).load(function () { ... });
```

Load events only fire on elements that have a URL associated with them, like images. You can however bind to the `window` load event which fires when all the elements on a page have loaded.

Alternatively you can bind to the `document.ready` event handler that fires when the DOM is ready to be manipulated. In jQuery we do this like so:

```
$(function () {
   //run code here
});
```

### Update

If you add elements to the DOM, do work on them before doing so:

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    $('body').append($('<div />').addClass('some-class').text('Some Text').on('click', function () { alert('Ouch! You poked me.'); }));
});
```

Notice I ran some jQuery functions on an element I created using jQuery before appending it to the DOM.

Comment: what if I want to bind the event when element is loaded or created(better to say)?

Comment: You can only bind to the `load` event for elements that have URLs, like images. It depends on how you are adding elements to the DOM, but you should run the code needed on them before adding them to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

.load is used as an ajax function in essence. you are trying to use it like a DOM load event.

Comment: See my comment on Trevor's answer.